# Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$. Let $A+B:=\{a+b|a\in A,b\in B\}$. Prove $\inf(A+B)=\inf A+\inf B$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$.  Let $A+B:=\{a+b$ | $a\in A,b\in B\}$.  Prove $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$ and $\inf(A+B)=\inf A+\inf B$.

I've already proven $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$, but I'm stuck on $\inf(A+B)=\inf A+\inf B$.

Comment: How did you prove the $\sup$ part? Cannot you see how to adapt the proof to $\inf$? It is a matter of switching some inequalities and signs.

Comment: Let $-A:=\{-a:a\in A\}$. Can you use the fact that $-\sup -A=\inf A$?

Comment: ...I had not remembered that $\sup(-A)=\inf A$. Thank you! ^_^

Comment: @DesperateFluffy You're missing a sign.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff You're quite right ^_^ $-\sup(-A)=\inf A$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative argument to the clever proof suggested in the comment section would be the following. For all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ we have $\inf(A)\le a$ and $\inf(B)\le b$ so:

$\inf(A)+\inf(B)\le a+b$

$a,b$ were arbitrary so $\inf(A)+\inf(B)\le \inf(A+B)$.

There is an element $c\in A$ such that $c-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\le\inf(A)$ and $d\in B$ such that $d-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\le\inf(B)$ so that:

$\inf(A+B)\le c+d\le \inf(A)+\inf(B)+\epsilon$

$\epsilon$ was arbitrary so we get the opposite inequality.